# Is there a reason why hr elements cannot be used as anchors?

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I've got a webpage in standard FAQ format, with each question listed as a link to its answer.

We have several `hr` elements that have been used as anchors - each with a unique assigned `id` attribute - but links don't appear to be functioning properly.

Anchor links appear to work with other elements, but not `hr` - and I can't find anything online suggesting that `hr` elements cannot be targeted as anchor points.

Can I not use `hr` elements for anchor link destinations for some reason?

**Example, using edited content:**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#requirements">What are the technical requirements for using the online application system?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#jobboard">Which job board should I use to apply for a position?</a></li>
</ul>

<hr id="requirements" />
<h3>What are the technical requirements for using the online application system?</h3>
<hr />
<p>The COMPANY uses an online application system for most of our job postings. This system lets you create a profile to keep track of the positions you’ve applied for, provides confirmation that your application has been accepted, allows you to edit submitted applications up until the posting closing date, and notifies you via email of jobs that match your skills and interests.</p>

<hr id="jobboard" />
<h3>Which job board should I use to apply for a position?</h3>
<hr />
<p>COMPANY has a variety of employee groups, and certain groups may apply for positions on specific job boards. Here is a summary of what job board you should be checking:</p>
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just switch your `hr` elems to something else?

Comment: why not just put your id inside the h3 ?

Comment: It appears that the only fix will be to switch the id over into the associated h3. Which wouldn't be a problem, except the practice of linking to the hr has been used sitewide - hundreds of links in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't find anything online suggesting that `hr` elements cannot be targeted as anchor points.

The spec mandates that [*any* element with an ID may be designated as the target of a URL fragment](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#find-a-potential-indicated-element). No exceptions are stated, which implies that the rule applies to `hr`.

Linking to an `hr` element not working appears to be an issue with Google Chrome. It works just fine on every other browser. I'd consider that a Chrome bug.

As a workaround, remove the `hr` elements (all of them) and reassign the IDs to the `h3` elements. That is how IDs are intended to be used. The `hr` element is only needed when dividing a single section into discrete subsections where subheadings are unnecessary or inappropriate. Since each entry in the FAQ is a section in its own right with its own heading, those `hr`s are superfluous at best and inappropriate at worst. If you want horizontal lines to appear between sections, add borders with CSS instead of using `hr` elements.

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#requirements">What are the technical requirements for using the online application system?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#jobboard">Which job board should I use to apply for a position?</a></li>
</ul>

<h3 id="requirements">What are the technical requirements for using the online application system?</h3>
<p>The COMPANY uses an online application system for most of our job postings. This system lets you create a profile to keep track of the positions you’ve applied for, provides confirmation that your application has been accepted, allows you to edit submitted applications up until the posting closing date, and notifies you via email of jobs that match your skills and interests.</p>

<h3 id="jobboard">Which job board should I use to apply for a position?</h3>
<p>COMPANY has a variety of employee groups, and certain groups may apply for positions on specific job boards. Here is a summary of what job board you should be checking:</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the [HTML 5 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element) does support the use of an `ID` attribute on an `<hr>` element (via support for [Global Attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes)) , however in reality, it's going to come down to an issue of which browsers support this practice.

If you're finding that some browsers aren't working, I would highly encourage you to re-write your HTML code using more common coding techniques, like using `<div>` or `<a>` elements instead.